# How to hide everything except omnibox (the address bar) in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, toolbar, address-bar, omnibox

Here is the omnibox on the toolbar:

[image: Omnibox]

How to hide everything except it?

Thank you.

Comment: Could we hide everything even with Omnibox ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So you want a browser with no ability to control or correct anything?

Comment: No, just block everything on the top, except ominbox but the tabs and everything else should be there

Comment: You will likely have to re-write the Chrome Browser (if indeed that were possible).

Comment: I'm confused, do you want tabs to be there also or not? If not, your comment above is inaccurate.